# Issue processing JSON data into Select2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, parsing, coffeescript, jquery-select2

Im having an issue deciphering how to process my json data for Select2, part of this may also be that my coffeeScript isnt great.

I have the following in my controller

```
render :json => User.select(:name,:address1,:address2,:address3,:city,:postcode).order(:name).joins(:locations).take(10)
```

In my JS.coffee

```
$('.entityajax').select2
  ajax:
    url: 'lookupentity'
    dataType: 'json'
    delay: 250
    data: (params) ->
      {
        q: params.term
        page: params.page
      }  
    processResults: (data,params) -> 
      results: data
```

I belive im breaking down processing the data into the drop box , do i need to select the items to bring over or parse more ? #

Currently I'm returning "no results"

My Json for clarity

> [{"id":null,"name":".","address1":"2016-03-07 23:15:42 UTC","address2":"$2a$10$8N4sPUK7F6i9Y0f.eCH3eOQTX/5pVtWhtBQBz5nvpbkx6qp2fIVCW","address3":null,"city":null,"postcode":"$2a$10$N4JoGvzrw3GOE1Xc.dBJwOs.4dbRy7UJk5edrT6PMc6IWHdbxB8j6"},{"id":null,"name":"3B Construction","address1":"2016-03-07 23:07:23 UTC","address2":"$2a$10$TAyBjnN3MCNdiUQbaC6xVeFObu/jIuM6mrLA3FQynHDIBFFwS2fde","address3":null,"city":null,"postcode":"$2a$10$/mCe1LrMM3.BTk3JvDjCYeLBR729xKKuPbUMrgoOR0eXv/Ts/eoq2"},{"id":null,"name":"A \u0026 A Business Management Ltd","address1":"2016-03-07 23:07:43 UTC","address2":"$2a$10$XOZdqmvz7qMsprDL3/2KV.GXuZdiiqRTwcnSPpcPRMWq.1gVgQn9C","address3":null,"city":null,"postcode":"$2a$10$4ph/se7XBAn2s5t1bPRSt.KN5iuXcVT4VmCpTawG9YBtgttJ9N5wq"},{"id":null,"name":"A \u0026 A Nicholson","address1":"2016-03-07 23:11:29 UTC","address2":"$2a$10$TeO6FSsOwfti8Nis2h75ae5hzl0lkFu.PSaGzvih0eKYsSuj9qLvy","address3":null,"city":null,"postcode":"$2a$10$h3aMMnogKdP3ClaqiTHH0eXbhixmWUHq3Ns3UdEn6Ee/EkSPRt9qa"},{"id":null,"name":"A McNeil","address1":"2016-03-07 23:16:00 UTC","address2":"$2a$10$s3t6tIRll/a8OTA.H7.iUOWaaa5eLVS/W9oqkm09/U32yIIQNU7w6","address3":null,"city":null,"postcode":"$2a$10$PtksnmryJK32zmUo2IW9e.npo8xhbYESLVz..vA0j/3mLKPQ/YHYG"},{"id":null,"name":"A Whiteside Joinery Contractor","address1":"2016-03-07 23:12:43 UTC","address2":"$2a$10$KUSUD8QGWZL1SZGL58TL2OVtXtiPSwVZBJFgpuBIoL/9f4eug42Py","address3":null,"city":null,"postcode":"$2a$10$AK51VCRYrWxLSES9nvc3nePyxJxtUAt2i0SWkbEY2xfy5MYZrBzxq"},{"id":null,"name":"A. B. Hastings \u0026 Sons","address1":"2016-03-07 23:13:24 UTC","address2":"$2a$10$zi81dQgQhyFLIc9QU35hR.iRy8NKUMwzmlHb7Vzlkf15vdgr.7Noa","address3":null,"city":null,"postcode":"$2a$10$/N7zXwuhCxHmhtPRaT9PG.2GXQsUHo8BFcW2gS8Ocr1CHrcRfI6qq"},{"id":null,"name":"A. J. Plasterers","address1":"2016-03-07 23:07:25 UTC","address2":"$2a$10$IsvjUtPiNz8uzpc9F6hja.g5hPUqRljG5BS2JmVgjRdLOCnctEXBO","address3":null,"city":null,"postcode":"$2a$10$awsBZd3EspE4k95Yh742huTi.I512zcnM1wmYcDqYWCCKgWHPgFWW"},{"id":null,"name":"A..W. Jenkins Forest Products","address1":"2016-03-07 23:10:11 UTC","address2":"$2a$10$o6bRzL0Ma0R20ernIH0U8u1NRf/AdZ1IIch//JwmrO84VKl4EtyBK","address3":null,"city":null,"postcode":"$2a$10$jIaC8k0oAYpXce3vYKB1PO.s.puRCPTVdBnhQnNVpcAtgHOyofTuy"},{"id":null,"name":"A.Currie","address1":"2016-03-07 23:14:35 UTC","address2":"$2a$10$xJtR5Vua2qO083F76pR0ou66B4LW3dWAZ.xW7TlRd/IOU6RWDc5tG","address3":null,"city":null,"postcode":"$2a$10$SzGwv3HwLSmO/6UWKVONHenz9X2p6QpGH5FLiaaIvwJ0qKlVYPZ42"}]

Answer (score 0):

For those struggling I have left question open.

It was in the structure of the JSON

select2 is by default looking for an item in the JSON called TEXT I simply selected AS in my SQL query rename the name field but believe you can rename in the javascript part

select2 looks for item ID,TEXT and you can pass selected: true or disabled :true as well.